# Only split on the first occurence of a character

Tags: powershell

If I have a string like

```
foo:bar baz:count
```

and I want to split on the first occurrence of `:` and get an array returned which contains only two elements:

- A string which is the element before the first colon.
- A string which is everything after the first colon.

How can I achieve this in Powershell?

Answer (score 18):

`-split` operator allows you to specify maximum number of substrings to return:

```
'foo:bar baz:count' -split ':',2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `IndexOf()` to find first occurance of ':'

Take the substring from the beginning until the index of ':'

Take the rest of the string from the ':' to the end.

Code:

```
$foobar = "foo:bar baz:count"
$pos = $foobar.IndexOf(":")
$leftPart = $foobar.Substring(0, $pos)
$rightPart = $foobar.Substring($pos+1)
```